# iText7 Layout Problems

Tags: c#, itext7

this question I have today is hard to define clearly but I will do my best.
My problem is the following:

**How do I create 'blocks' of some sort on a canvas which I can use to draw lines and such on without worrying about drawing outside this box**

What is my solution so far?

**I'm using ConcatMatrix on the PdfCanvas object to move the coordinate system to where I want to draw. Then before drawing I make sure that any LineTo or MoveTo is not greate than the max x value of this 'block'**

So, there must be some predefined class or functionality which lets me do this without having to create a whole custom library just for this purpose.

[image]

Basically, I want to be able to have these boxes which should somehow act like a PdfCanvas, which I can place on the Pdf where I want, draw, do whatever inside them, and it should be bounded inside this box.
I have been looking everywhere. Does anyone know if this even can be done?

So, what was my problem with my solution?

Look on the left side of the picture, box number 2. If I would simply use CurveTo with max x value and given y value (since y value is below max) then the curve would look different, not actually cut of like to the right hand side.
Well, you get the point.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for the `clip` operator. Could you take a look at my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821326/how-to-set-line-width-on-template-clipping Basically, you create the path of the rectangle and define this as a clipping path.

Comment: I can't find PdfTemplate for c#. Do u happend to know where it is, or the equivalent?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie How do I define it as a clipping path?

Comment: Your iText version is unclear. You use the tags [tag:itext] and [tag:itext7], the former being for versions up to 5.5.x and the latter for 7.x. In the question title you use the name iTextSharp which was the name of the .Net iText up to 5.5.x. So Bruno referenced a iText 5.5.x solution. But probably you instead do have a version 7.x?

Comment: There are iText 7 examples in the official FAQ, see for instance: [How to tell iText how to clip text to fit in a cell?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/tables/itext7-how-tell-itext-how-clip-text-fit-cell)

Comment: That is correct, im using the iText 7, i just assumed it was a name for the C# version of the API.

Comment: It was for iText5, but we're trying to move people away from it for iText7, since the official name is iText7 for .Net